# SQL Query to change group clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT age_groups.Name as name, avg(scores.score) as avg 
FROM scores 
JOIN users ON scores.id = users.id 
JOIN age_groups on user.age_group = age_groups.id;
```

There are 5 age groups: 0-10, 11-20, 21-30, 31-40, 41-50.

I'd like to have only three age groups in my results: 0-30, 31-40, and 41-50.

What statements would allow me to group three age groups together?

EDIT:

The age_groups table looks like this:

```
ID - Name
1 - 0-10
2 - 11-20
3 - 21-30
...etc
```

Comment: If you provide table definition. it's helpful to answer.

Comment: Does your age groups table have the start and end of the respective group as a numerical value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case` to combine age groups.  First, though, your query is missing `group by`, so it should read more like:

```
SELECT ag.Name as name, avg(s.score) as avg
FROM scores s JOIN
     users u
     ON s.id = u.id JOIN
     age_groups ag
     on u.age_group = ag.id
GROUP BY ag.Name;
```

You can then do what you want as:

```
SELECT (case when ag.Name in ('0-10', '11-20', '21-30') then '0-30'
             else ag.Name
        end) as MyAgeGroup, avg(s.score) as avg
FROM scores s JOIN
     users u
     ON s.id = u.id JOIN
     age_groups ag
     on u.age_group = ag.id
GROUP BY (case when ag.Name in ('0-10', '11-20', '21-30') then '0-30'
               else ag.Name
          end);
```

Comment: I suggest `GROUP BY MyAgeGroup` so you don't have to repeat the `CASE`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to replace "age_groups.Name" in your select clause with a case statement which remaps each of the contributing ranges to your desired range:

```
CASE age_groups.Name
  WHEN '0-10'
  THEN '0-30'
  WHEN '10-20'
  THEN '0-30'
  WHEN '20-30'
  THEN '0-30'
  ELSE age_groups.Name
END AS Name
```

and also add this to the bottom with a GROUP BY clause (e.g., GROUP BY CASE WHEN ...)

However, if this type of thing might be done frequently, then I would recommend a longer term solution, which is to add numeric bounds to the age groups in your age group table such as Age_Group_Lower_Bound (integer) and Age_Group_Upper_Bound (integer) (e.g., your 0-10 row would then have Age_Group_Lower_Bound=0 and Age_Group_Upper_Bound=10).  Once these are in place, your original query could use these, e.g.,:

```
CASE
  WHEN age_groups.Age_Group_Upper_Bound <= 30
  THEN '0-30'
  ELSE age_Groups.Name
END
```

Here's an example of that, taking it further with more ranges getting grouped together, e.g.:

```
CASE
  WHEN age_groups.Age_Group_Upper_Bound <= 20
  THEN '0-20'
  WHEN age_groups.Age_Group_Upper_Bound <= 40
  THEN '20-40'
  WHEN age_groups.Age_Group_Upper_Bound <= 60
  THEN '40-60'
  ELSE '60+'
END
```